# Azure Devops deploying Azure C# Function

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions

I'm failing to use the Azure Devops Release management to deploy my Azure Functions.

**Build**

In the build pipeline, I've got two tasks:

- dotnet publish
- publich release artifact

[image]

This step succeeds
The artifact is published into /drop/a.zip

[image]

**Release**

In this step I have a Dev environment.
and a single task:

- Azure Function App Deploy.

Credentials and which app to deploy to is specified.

There is a path specified to the release artifact like so:
[image]

I can even browse the path with the browse button in that image. and navigate to and pick the correct zip there.

But once this task runs. it all ends with a 
`##[error]Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a\DotnetFunctions-CI\drop\a.zip`

I am aware there are other questions here on SO bringing up the same question. however the answers I've seen there does not solve the issue here.

What am I missing?

Comment: Look at the "Download Artifacts" step of your release. Is the file being downloaded? Is it being downloaded *to the location you specified*?

Answer (score 0):

I've had issue with the release pipeline not finding an artifact. What I've started doing is using the double wildcard search instead of the full path. [image]

That is in my Deploy Azure App Service task inside the release pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

My azure function works:

In Build :
Visual Studio Build Task :
Add following arguments in MSBuild section :

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\$(BuildConfiguration)\\"
```

here is my build and release:
**Build Configuration**:
[image]

[image]

**Release** :

[image]